# How do I fix this light fixture wiring situation?

Tags: electrical, safety

imagine a light fixture, with no ground wire, this is mounted to aluminum which is painted white, The hot and neutral leaves from the wire are exposed to the open air and connected to exposed Romex in contact with the aluminum soffit fascia. The wire nuts are exposed with no protection. There is also no ground wire present. The sky's blue with light clouds, the vinyl siding is white with light algae stains, below the fixture is a catenary wire that appears to be connected to an orange extension cord that has been cut open and used as an improvised permanent wire.

[image]

Should I route the wire through PVC into the back of a junction box then run a flexible watertight conduit to the light fixture? There's no ground on the romex.

Comment: What was there before ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What Romex, there's nothing that looks like that in your photo? Anyway, that type of cable is not allowed to be used outdoors or in wet locations.

Comment: The Romex appears to be supported by another cable.  Is that other cable for high voltage or low voltage wiring?  Is it just a 3-way high voltage splice?  Sorry but I have more questions than answers based on the photo.  More than likely, you're going to have to remove all of the old work and start over.

Comment: [Rod Serling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rod_Serling), is that you? That's some... creative writing.

Comment: @FreeMan My apologies, I thought the text above the photo would be alt text on the photo and only accessible to those with screen readers.

Comment: Or those whose organizations have decided to block imgur links. In either case, that's something else...

Answer (score 4):

What you have there is an amateurish, dangerous, mess.

The only way to make mounting a light safe and proper is to get a weather tight outdoor box mounted. (The box must be proper for the light)
Then wire, (rated properly for the breaker it is fed by), is run in weather tight conduit.

You need a hot, neutral and a ground.

The conduit needs to be run through the wall, or terminate into another weathertight box that is fed through the wall by the proper wire or cable.

Whether inside or outside any splice or connection must be in a box that is accessible. ( no wirenuts in tape hanging anywhere.)

If all that is done, a proper outdoor rated light can be attached.

Should any of this be outside your understanding or comfort level, you should refer to a licensed electrician.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the fixture with a low voltage outdoor LED one.  Use the existing wires coming out of the wall to feed low voltage from a convenient location inside the attic.   There, place a junction box and PSU for the new light.